# Repeatedly wraps selected text in <span> instead of changing the current <span>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a Word clone and I'm trying to make a bold button which toggles the boldness of the selected text.

Whenever I click the bold button, it wraps the selected text in a `<span>`. However, when I click it again, instead of turning that `<span style="font-weight: bold;">` into a `<span style="font-weight: 400;">`, it wraps it in another span.

How do I change the style of the current `<span>` instead of wrapping it in another one?

```js
let isBold = false;

function applyText(type) {
  let selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
    let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.appendChild(range.cloneContents());

    if (type === 'bold') {
      if (isBold) {
        span.style.fontWeight = 'normal';
      } else {
        span.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
      }
      isBold = !isBold;
    }

    range.deleteContents();
    range.insertNode(span);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="editor-area" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Type your text here..."></div>
<button onclick="applyText('bold')"><i class="fa-solid fa-bold">Bold</i></button>
```

Comment: Currently, you are creating a new span and appending the range contents to that span. What have you tried to update the original span?

Comment: hey @tnarh, can you remove the un necessary code and put the code that is related to the bold thing? and your snippet not seems to be working fine!

Comment: your method is bad, you must create a dynamic tree structure on your text where each node contains the attribution of one or more styles to their portion of text concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of always creating a new span when calling the applyText function, you could check if a span is already existing e.g. by using document.getElementById("my-span") and then apply the styles in a way you have done already. Naturally, if there is no span you should create one like you are currently doing. Another option could be to already include the span and not create it in the applyText function.